# How to select single button on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue in an UITableView as I need to place a button on each row of the tableview and if i click the button, it gets selected at a time and selecting is like toggle. How to achieve this, please help me out to solve this problem.

Below is the following code that am trying to get it out. I am creating button on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as shown below:

```
UIButton  *Btn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
Btn .frame = CGRectMake(3, 10, 33, 30);
[Btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
Btn.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.contentView addSubview:Btn];
```

and the `method:` for button action:

```
-(void)method:(UIButton*)sender
{

     NSIndexPath  *indexpath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];

     Btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    //Btn.tag=sender.tag;
    [Btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're experiencing? What happens with the code that you've posted?

Answer (score 1):

You have an array to store whether the button of a cell is selected or not. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you should set 2 images for 2 states `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateSelected` of the button:

```
[Btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[Btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then in the `method:` function, you switch the state of the button via `Btn.selected` based on the value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage * btnLinkNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"];
[cell.linkButton setImage:btnLinkNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Add image to button for pressed state
UIImage * btnLinkHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"deselect.png"];
[cell.linkButton setImage:btnLinkHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```